# Modifications to data obtained through 'require' were not implemented

Tags: javascript, node.js

**app.js**

```
var temp = require('./data');

temp.setId(1);
temp.setName('Tushar', 'Mudgal');
temp.setCity('New Delhi');
temp.setPh(9999421591);

var temp2 = require('./data');

// temp2.setId(2);
// temp2.setName('Saurabh', 'Mudgal');
// temp2.setCity('New Delhi');
// temp2.setPh(9999425085);

console.log(temp.getInfo());

console.log(temp2.getInfo());
```

When I executed the script above via `node`, I received this output:

```
tourist@linux:~/Desktop/backend/modules2/customer$ node app.js 
{ name: 'Tushar Mudgal',
  cid: 1,
  ad_city: 'New Delhi',
  phno: 9999421591 }
{ name: 'Tushar Mudgal',
  cid: 1,
  ad_city: 'New Delhi',
  phno: 9999421591 }
```

I would like to know why `temp2` contains the same data as `temp`.

The `data` folder consist of an `index.js` file which contains the definitions of all the functions executed in the `app.js` file.

Comment: We have no idea what's inside `./data`, so we can't help you. If you add more info about that file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js caches modules, so require(...) is *not* the same as readFile(...): once Node's loaded in a module, it caches the module export, and simple refers back to that on any subsequent require(...) call for the same thing.

So:

```
// load module into cache and return its exports.
// the variable temp is an _alias_ for these exports.
var temp = require('./data');

// modify temp, and because it's just an alias, that means
// modify the data.js exports that you told Node to require in.
modify(temp);

// set up a new alias for the data.js module. Node
// points you to its cache, so any changes you made earlier
// are still in effect.
var temp2 = require('./data');
```

Bottom line: don't use `require` if you need to load file data. Only use it if you need to load in a real module.